# Does this joist need to be reinforced?

Tags: joists

I'm running some wiring and came upon this.  One-story 1952-ish house.  Joist is 2x10.  Pics are before and after removal of some "support" piece.  Looking up at the basement laundry room ceiling.

It's just a piece of wooden crate (marked "ACID RESISTING ENAMEL") that's warped and poorly fastened with three nails.  It ends right at the left side of the picture.

Do I even need this?  Should I replace it with something that more fully fills the area?

The next joist over has the same holes for cables and isn't reinforced.  I do plan to put another 1/2" hole through here for another electrical cable.

Six feet to the left the joist sits on the outer cinder block wall of the house.  Six feet to the right the joist sits on an interior cinder block wall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the other side of the "supported" joist look like?

Comment: @JACK The other side is normal, just like the "after" pic.

Comment: To be honest, I can't see the purpose of the removed, "warped" joist.  It didn't appear to be bearing  on anything in the right side of the picture.

Comment: the holes for the corrugated pipes  (or whatever they are) look like they were drilled in allowed locations (so not needing reinforcement for that) , but that water damage is a worry.

Comment: @Jasen Not corrugated pipes; that's armored electrical cable.  And not water damage; it's cement staining from the original bathroom install.  Both common sights in homes of this age.